# How to remove unicode <U+00A6> from string?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a string like:

```
q <-"<U+00A6>  1000-66329"
```

I want to remove `<U+00A6>` and get only `1000 66329`.

I tried using:

```
gsub("\u00a6"," ", q,perl=T)
```

But it is not removing anything. How should I do `gsub` in order to get only `1000 66329`?

Comment: Split on delimiter (space?), then take the 2nd bit of text?

Comment: What does the assignment *actually* look like? Are you assigning the Unicode character U+00A6 or the literal character string `'<U+00A6>'`? Because that’s what your code is doing at the moment, and the rest doesn’t make much sense in light of that.

Comment: Actually I have data frame in which one column has values like "<U+00A6>  1000-66329" and this <U+00A6> is the unicode for broken bar symbol (¦) which is at the start of all values. I want to remove this unexpected symbol from my data.

Comment: Maybe try copying and pasting that ¦ into your gsub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I just want to remove unicode `<U+00A6>` which is at the beginning of string.

Then you do not need a `gsub`, you can use a `sub` with `"^\\s*<U\\+\\w+>\\s*"` pattern:

```
q <-"<U+00A6>  1000-66329"
sub("^\\s*<U\\+\\w+>\\s*", "", q)
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `<U\\+` - a literal char sequence `<U+`
- `\\w+` - 1 or more letters, digits or underscores
- `>` - a literal `>`
- `\\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces.

If you also need to replace the `-` with a space, add `|-` alternative and use `gsub` (since now we expect several replacements and the replacement must be a space - same is in [akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993968/3832970)):

```
trimws(gsub("^\\s*<U\\+\\w+>|-", " ", q))
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/YcJxM8)

Comment: This is removing the (ASCII) string `<U+00A6>`, not the _Unicode character_.

Comment: This is working perfectly for me. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: @HongOoi: Exactly, that is what OP has in the input.

Comment: @user6559913: FYI, the `"\u00a6"` pattern is incompatible with PCRE regex flavor, to match unicode code points, you need to use `\x{00a6}` notation. However, as you yourself mentioned, you have a literal `<U+...>` substring to remove, so you just do not need that.

Answer (score 3):

If  always is the first character, you can try:

```
substring("\U00A6 1000-66B29", 2)
```

if R prints the string as `<U+00A6>  1000-66329` instead of `¦ 1000-66B29` then `<U+00A6>` is interpreted as the string `"<U+00A6>"` instead of the unicode character. Then you can do:

```
substring("<U+00A6>  1000-66329",9)
```

Both ways the result is:

```
[1] "  1000-66329"
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But this is giving me "006  1000 66329" and i also have some of the strings containing alphabets also like                "<U+00A6> 1000-66B29".  I just want to remove unicode <U+00A6> which is at the beginning of string.

Answer (score 2):

We can also do

```
trimws(gsub("\\S+\\s+|-", " ", q))
#[1] "1000 66329"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing you should convert it to the appropriate format ... You have to set your local to UTF-8 like so:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8")
```

Maybe you will see the following message:

```
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored
```

In this case you should use `stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "zh")`

Here "zh" means "chinese". You should know which language you have to convert to. That's it