# How to remove unicode <U+2032> from string?

Tags: r, regex

I've used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993715/how-to-remove-unicode-u00a6-from-string), but it doesn't work.
My code include value like:

```
clients <- c("Greg Smith <U+2032>", "John Coolman", "Mr. Brown <U+2032>")
```

So I tried:

```
clients <- gsub("$\\s*<U\\+\\w+>", "", clients)
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: `gsub(" <[^>]+>", "", clients)`?

Answer (score 4):

```
clients <- gsub("[<].*[>]", "", clients)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `$` as the first character of your expression.  This matches the end of an expression, but only if it is the last character of the pattern:

```
> gsub("\\s*<U\\+\\w+>$", "", clients)
[1] "Greg Smith"   "John Coolman" "Mr. Brown"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove only unicode `<U+2032>`

```
clients <- c("Greg Smith <U+2032>", "John Coolman", "Mr. Brown <U+2032>")
clients <- gsub("<U\\+2032>", "", clients)
clients
# [1] "Greg Smith "   "John Coolman" "Mr. Brown "
```