# Escape Character in R

Tags: r, escaping

I'm trying to build a map colored by value. The column name for the values is: `Median House Price (<U+00A3>) - 2014`

I haven't been able to figure out how to escape the special characters correctly.

Should this rename work correctly?

`rename(BoroughDataMap, Median House Price 2014=Median House Price \(\<U\+00A3\>\) \- 2014)`

edit: error message is: `Error: unexpected symbol in "rename(BoroughDataMap, Median House"`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852024/how-to-remove-unicode-u2032-from-string) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993715/how-to-remove-unicode-u00a6-from-string) ?

Comment: yeah as you can see in the rename line, I'm escaping special characters using a backslash per those links but still getting the error so missing something.