# R - gsub to remove punctuation & numbers from string

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to remove punctuation and digits from `<U+200B>Chandler` to become `Chandler`. This is what I'm currently trying:

```
df$city <- gsub("[[:punct:]]|[[:digit:]]", "", df$city)
```

However, it doesn't do anything to change the cell in column 'city' in 'df'. When I search typeof(df), I get 'list'. This might have to do with it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993715/how-to-remove-unicode-u00a6-from-string)?

Comment: No, I haven't, thanks for sharing this link. I did try the `gsub` method as in this question but the `inconv` method (below) works best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second question first, `tyepof()` will always return `list` for a data frame, because [data frames are really just lists of equal length vectors](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#data-frames).

For the first question, it appears you have some Unicode encoded characters in your data. One good way to take care of these is to convert them, perhaps like:

```
df$city <- iconv(df$city, 'utf-8', 'ascii', sub = '')
```

It is also possible to `gsub` out characters on their hex code, like this:

```
df$city <- gsub('\u200B', '', df$city)
```

or even a range:

```
df$city <- gsub('[\u2000-\u20ff]', '', df$city)
```

But really I think the `iconv` approach is the way to go. In this usage it will just remove the character rather than render it, but that seems to be what you want.